# Imbedding theorem for Sobolev space $D^{k,p}$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I can't find any reference on the imbedding theorem for the Sobolev space $D^{k,p}$, which is defined by

$$D^{k,p}(\Omega)=\{u\in L_{loc}^{1}(\Omega)|D^{k} u\in L^{p}(\Omega)\}.$$
Is it the same as that for the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}$?

Comment: It depends on whether $\Omega$ is bounded or not. For bounded $\Omega$, it depends on whether $\partial\Omega$ is regular or not. There's a lot of publications in Russian. Maybe something was translated into English.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As my research fellow said, W^{k,p}=D^{k,p} when $\Omega$ is bounded and locally Lipschitz. But we just can't find the original reference. Well, we care more about the case $\Omega=\mathbb{R^{n}}$.

Answer (score 1):

For bounded domains $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geqslant 2$, satisfying the cone condition, the spaces coincide, *i.e.*, $D^{k,p}(\Omega)=W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.  Examples
of nonsmooth bounded domains $\Omega$ for which $D^{1,p}(\Omega)\neq W^{1,p}(\Omega)$,
*i.e.*, $D^{1,p}(\Omega)\not\subset L^p(\Omega)$, can be found in *"Sobolev spaces"* http://bookza.org/book/977600/c2bb9a by V.G. Mazya.  A domain $\Omega$ for which $D^{1,2}(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)$ is called the *Nikodym domain* — for details see pages 329–330 in *"Functional analysis. Theory and applications"* by R.E. Edwards (corrected edition http://bookza.org/book/763103/086133). The space 
$D^{k,p}(\Omega)$ was introduced by Sobolev in 1930-ies, and later studied in his book *"Some applications of functional analysis in mathematical physics"* originally published in Russian in 1950, while the English translation was published by the AMS in 1991 as *Translations of Mathematical Monographs*, **90** (see spaces $L_p^l$ therein http://bookza.org/book/685689/f6d2c1). See also spaces $L_2^{(m)}$ in the book 
*"The theory of cubature formulas"*  by Sobolev & Vaskevich http://bookza.org/book/2129623/ee52eb.

It might be helpful to remark that among the norms introduced so far on $D^{k,p}(\Omega)$, most suitable in all respects seems to be the norm
$$
\|u\|_{D^{k,p}(\Omega)}=\|u\|_{L^p(\omega)}+
\sum_{|\alpha|=k}\|D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}
$$
with some chosen bounded open subset $\omega\subset\Omega$,  *e.g.*, some open ball.